# What's the "to little endian" equivalent of htonl?

Tags: c, embedded, endianness

I want to write platform independent code that fills an array of 32-bit ints, which is then transmitted to a little-endian embedded machine.

If the target were big-endian, I'd use `htonl` to convert from host order (whatever that may be) to network (big-endian) order.  But I want to go to little endian, regardless of the host order.  I certainly can't use the "opposite" `ntohl` - since that does the exact same swapping.

Is there a standard "h-to-LittleEndian-l" function in C?

I could roll my own with `bswap_32(htonl(X))`, but I'm not sure I trust the compiler not to generate a double swap on little endian machines.

Comment: I guess it is a duplicate, but I don't like any of those answers - they all force me to either know the host architecture or risk the double swap.   I'm really surprised there is no "standard" header with this function.

Comment: What OS? Quite a few have an `<endian.h>` or `<sys/endian.h>` with conversion functions. Linux example: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html

Comment: *they all force me to either know the host architecture* – `int foo = 0xaaff; bool little_endian = *(char unsigned *)&foo == 0xaa;`?

Comment: There is no standard (as in C standard) functions to do the swapping. You have to implement them yourself. There are `<endian.h>` and `<sys/endian.h>` and `bswap{16,32}` and `betoh{16,32}` and similar, but these all are OS and environment specific. `htonl` and `ntohl` are also no standard, so assuming you use them, you already assume that you know something about the environment. Moreover the C standard does not say anything about endianess of data, swapping endianess all is not standard.

Comment: The existence of `htonl` tells me something about the software environment, but nothing about the hardware.  And although it is not a true C standard, it is "standard enough" -  if it exists, I trust it will do the right thing.

Comment: @Shawn's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: If you truly wanted platform independence, you'd simply use htonl and ntohl at both ends. That is the purpose of these functions.  What you are asking for is not platform independent; it is dependent on the byte order if your embedded system.  Apart from that a host order to little-endian function is trivial to implement and could have taken you less time than it took to write the question, (or this comment for that matter).

Comment: This comment has been bugging me since it was written.  I do want, and did achieve true platform independence - for the non-embedded end of the system. Forcing the over-the-wire data to be in network order is stupid when it forces the resource-limited platform to double its work to unpack the data stream.  What I needed, and found, was a way to let the application code run correctly and efficiently on whichever unix-y platform it was compiled on.  <endian.h> ftw.